# How maximum baudrate will be determined for i2c

Tags: i2c

I've seen standard baud for typicall i2c is 100k ,fast mode **400k**

How one can determine it?

Comment: Determine where? On the working device?

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are defined in the [I2C standard, published by NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) (previously Philips).

In practice the limits are defined by hardware, you would have to ask on [Electronics stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) about that.